# Not Generate Android APK Version wise using devops Pipeline after changes version code in build gradle and commit

Tags: android, azure-devops, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment

I have committed code after change Version Code in app Build Gradle File.
I have run the pipeline in Azure DevOps.
Complete the pipeline task and generate APK on drop folder but When I have published APK play store then got a message from Play store "Apk Version is already Used".

Answer (score 0):

If changing versionCode in the build.gradle file is not working. 
you can try **removing** the versionCode and versionName located under the default config, and add the versionCode and versionName in AndroidManifest.xml: Please check this [thread](https://github.com/bitrise-steplib/steps-google-play-deploy/issues/31).

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0">
```

And also make sure the pipeline builds against the right branch to which the versionCode change is committed.

If you would like to automatically increase the version code, Please check [auto Increase the version code in Android apk using Fastlane](https://medium.com/codespace69/how-we-can-auto-increase-the-version-code-in-android-apk-using-fastlane-14c2b7af6704)

Comment: Hi @Kaushal Patel Did you check out above mentioned thread,  how did it go with above solution?